# Americans are puzzled vs Americans puzzled

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs

> 1. Americans are puzzled
> 2. Americans puzzled

Which one is correct? I believe 2nd one is grammatically correct, but I see the usage of 1st also.

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to use such an unlikely subject as ***Americans*** here. The grammatical issues are just the same with *John is puzzled* compared to *John puzzled*. And the answer is that intransitive ***past*** tense *John puzzled* is grammatically valid, but such a form would almost never be used by a native speaker in *any* context. But *Americans puzzled* would often appear as a grammatically ***incorrect*** version of *Americans **are** puzzled* in "newspaper headlinese" which frequently omits unimportant verbs such as *to be* and *to have*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both correct, when used properly. The problem is, they're phrases, not complete sentences (sort of). Consider the following two sentences:

1) Americans are puzzled by the alien spacecraft hovering over Montana.

2) Americans puzzled over the alien spacecraft hovering over Montana.

In the first sentence, Americans (as a whole) are confused and confounded by an alien spacecraft hovering over a state.

In the second sentence, Americans are thinking about an alien spacecraft hovering over a state. They are still confused, but are thinking about it - why is it there, what is it doing, is it stealing our cows, etc.

Both phrases could be used in certain situations. The only one that is a sentence on its own, however, is "Americans are puzzled." This states that Americans in general are attempting to figure something out (what, we don't know).

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct, but distinguished based on usage.

Americans puzzled: *It is past tense with active voice*.
e.g.> Americans puzzled rest of World by their technology.

Americans are puzzled: *It is a present tense with passive voice*.
e.g.> Americans are puzzled by the Russians' technology.

Comment: Your first sentence should read "Americans puzzled *the* rest of *the* world *with* their technology." Otherwise, good post!